# Symbols become question marks in terminal

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have a problem when printing some symbols in my terminal. They become question marks, but I can't seem to fix it I am printing:

```
System.out.println("╭" + "─".repeat(msg.length()) + "╮");
System.out.println("│" + msg + "│");
System.out.println("│" + " ".repeat(msg.length()) + "│");
System.out.println( "│" + msg2 + " ".repeat(msg.length() - msg2.length()) + "│" ); 
System.out.println("╰" + "─".repeat(msg.length()) + "╯");
```

But all of the lines I try to print becomes question marks in my terminal. Does anyone have a solution?

```
?????????????????????????????????????????????? ? 
WebServer running on http://localhost:8080 ? ? ? ? 

Boot-up time: 0,8588 seconds. ? ??????????????????????????????????????????????
```

Seems like it doesn't "know" the symbols, and they are replaced by a "?" instead

I have tried to change the encoding, but it dosent change the encoding in the terminal.

I use MacBook.

Comment: Is your terminal set up to handle utf-8? I assume it isn't and the encoding it uses doesn't support those characters.

Comment: @Thomas: I do not think that it is the problem (on Mac we expect terminals to be able to support UTF-8 natively). I think MrMikkel problem is the character set in the locale. Probably you are running it as root, so without UTF-8 support (for reasons!)

Comment: Ahhh, how would I be able set up my terminal to handle Utf-8 or change the character set in the locale?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi well, the OP states "I have tried to change the encoding" so I'd assume they already tried to set it. However, it might be good to have more information. @OP (MrMikkel): can you provide the output of `Charset.defaultCharset()`, how you tried to change the encoding as well as the encoding of your terminal? (https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/use-international-character-encodings-trml15220/mac indicates utf-8 or at least international characters might not be supported by default)

Comment: Output provided from Charset.defaultCharset():  US-ASCII

Comment: @Thomas I have enabled all encodings in terminal settings

Comment: @MrMikkel: `locale -a` will give you all locales. Ev. you should change locale e.g. before executing your script) to one which support UTF-8.

Comment: Did you try starting your application with `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`? `Charset.defaultCharset()` would read that property once and cache the result. So you can't change it later.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Ahh I see - How do I change locale?

Comment: @Thomas If I write in the terminal -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 - It just says Command not found

Comment: No, you need to add that property to the command you're using to start your application, e.g. `java -D... YourApp`. If you're using terminal scripts you'd need to set it there somewhere.

Comment: @Thomas hmm Im not sure I understand. The funny thing is that it worked for me until I reinstalled my vs-code

Comment: The property I shared needs to be part of the command you use to start the application. Where to put it depends on how you start it - if directly from the command line then add it there (I'm no Mac user but it seems you _might_ have to surround the property=value portion with double quotes), if you're using a shell script (or how it's called on Mac) then put it there, if you're starting the application from VS Code then put it into the run configuration VS Code is using (didn't use that myself so not sure where that would be).

Comment: @Thomas I run my application inside vs code. I have a main class that runs my different object classes

Comment: E.g. `LANG=en_US.utf8` before executing your program

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Should I write it directly in the terminal?

Comment: yes. Either the line before, so you change the locale, or just before your command (so with a space): in this later case you will change the locale only for the program in the same line

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi if I write: LANG=en_US.utf8 cradle run tt gives me the error:

error: unmappable character (0xAF) for encoding US-ASCII
    System.out.println("???" + "???".repeat(msg.length()) + "???");